# Connection.query() return value cannot be duplicated outside the function

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
function getData(callback){
    const sql =`INSERT INTO receipiant (name, address ,bloodgroup,emailid ,phonenumber ) VALUES ('${name}','${address}','${bloodgroup}','${emailid}','${phonenumber}');SELECT bloodbank.name, donor.donname,donor.phoneno,donor.address,donor.emailid,donor.dateofbirth FROM bloodbank INNER JOIN donor ON donor.bbid=bloodbank.idbloodbank WHERE donor.bloodgroup = '${bloodgroup}'`
    connection.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
        if(err)
            callback(err,null)
        else
            callback(null,result)


    })
}
var msgres
getData(function(err,data){
    if (err) {
        // error handling code goes here
        console.log("ERROR : ",err);            
    } else {            
        // code to execute on data retrieval
        // console.log("result from db is : ",data); 
        var msgres = Object.assign({},data) 
    }    

});

  console.log(msgres)
```

*the data is being copied in the msgres variable in the function and the msgres is displaying only within the function but when i try to log it outside of the function its showing me the value as undefined but i have already declared the variable outside the function.I also tried using the let keyword but it still shows the same but when i console log it inside the function it works fine.*

Comment: Your second console.log runs before the data comes out of the db, as the log is synchronous but retrieval async. Also, we if that weren't the case, it still wouldn't work because you declare msgres inside your function as a new var, instead of assigning to the existing variable

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because getData has not finished execution when you log msgres.

In node.js, most i/o is asynchronous, so you'll see this type of issue a lot.

The best way to proceed is to pass the data to a handler function in the callback.

You don't need to clone the returned data either, just pass it back!

For example:

```
function processData(data) {
    console.log("processData: processing: ", data);
    // do whatever with data here.
}

getData(function(err,data){
    if (err) {
        // error handling code goes here
        console.log("ERROR : ",err);            
    } else {            
         // code to execute on data retrieval
        console.log("result from db is : ",data);           
        processData(data);
    }    
});
```